# How to convert NSIndexPath to NSString-iOS

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsindexpath

I want to convert `NSIndexPath` to `NSString`. How would I do it?
I have to use this:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadedFile:(NSString*)sourcePath 
{
    [client deletePath:@"/objc/boston_copy.jpg"];
}
```

inside commitEditingStyle method where I only get `NSIndexPath` as input.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView 
        commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
        forRowAtIndexPath :(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{                  
    [self.itemArray  removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];          
    [aTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                      withRowAnimation:YES];    
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]
                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];   
}
```

Comment: How are you supposed to get that from a set of numbers? We are going to need more information, or this question will be closed.

Comment: why do you want to convert it in NSString?

Comment: the parameter that deletePath takes-it is NSString. Can I simply typecast it? is I have (NSIndex Path*)indexPath; can I do (NSString*)indexPath and give it to deletePath.

Comment: An NSIndexPath is effectively just an array of integers, so casting it won't do anything useful.

Comment: okay. What do I do? I need to convert the information to NSString

Comment: This is a good question. There can be many reasons someone might want to do this. Perhaps displaying to the user, sending over the wire, saving in a database, logging, or hovering in the debugger.

Answer (score 5):

I made this a category on NSIndexPath at one point in time:

```
@interface NSIndexPath (StringForCollection)

-(NSString *)stringForCollection;

@end

@implementation NSIndexPath (StringForCollection)

-(NSString *)stringForCollection
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d",self.section,self.row];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4):

I made this extension to help with debugging:

```
@interface NSIndexPath (DBExtensions)
- (NSString *)indexPathString;
@end

@implementation NSIndexPath (DBExtensions)
- (NSString *)indexPathString;
{
  NSMutableString *indexString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",[self indexAtPosition:0]];
  for (int i = 1; i < [self length]; i++){
    [indexString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@".%lu", [self indexAtPosition:i]]];
  }
  return indexString;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert an NSIndexPath to a string -- an NSIndexPath is effectively just an array of integers. Assuming by "convert" you mean that you want to access the data associated with a particular path, you have to go back to the source of that data.

If you generated the table from an array of objects, which is commonly the case, then you'll simply look at the object at the array index equal to the first element of the indexPath. If the table is sectioned then you need to look at how the data was accessed in order to create the sections -- it likely relates to sorting of the objects based on some object property.

There's no conversion, there's just looking at the data source the same way it was accessed when generating the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension NSIndexPath {
    var prettyString: String {
        var strings = [String]()
        for position in 0..<length {
            strings.append(String(indexAtPosition(position)))
        }
        return strings.joinWithSeparator("_")
    }
}
```